# How to make a function to accept dynamic arguments?

Tags: lua

When dealing with function(v1,v2,v3) or function(...) there doesn't seem to be a good way of handling changes to where the arguments are placed when calling the function.

Example Function:

```lua
my_function(v1,v2,v3) {
  print(v1, v2, v3)
}
```

Example args Function:

```lua
my_args_func(...) {
  local arg = {...}
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
    print(v)
  end
}
```

From the above 2 examples you can do

```
my_function(set1,set2,set3)
my_arg_func(set1,set2,set3)
```

But if you want to make changes to either of them, it becomes the same chore of managing all the functions parameter updates.

Say we want to add a new value for both functions. newval10.

the my_function() we would be forced to put it on the end, like my_function(v1,v2,v3,newval10) or things wouldn't work right unless we update both the call and the function params it's accepting.

The same goes for func(...) where we only know the index value and the actual value. not what they represent. Is there a way to have a function like

```
local my_generic_func(...) {
  -stuff goes here
}
if my_generic_func(v1,v2,v3) then return end
```

could be updated with my_generic_func(v1,v5,v3,v4,v2) and the function would know where each value actually is.

Comment: [Yes](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to give a function a single parameter with any name, then use that as the rest of the arguments.

```lua
local function generic(par)
  _generic(par.arg1 or 0, --sets a default value of 0
    par.arg2 or "arg2",
    par.arg3 --default is "false" or "nil"
  )
end
```

The usage of this would be as follows:

```lua
a = generic{12,"alpha"} --note the use of curly braces
```

Which would perform the `generic` function with arguments `12`, `"alpha"`, and default `nil`.

To specifically denote which variable you're setting, you can do:

```lua
a = generic{arg1=12,arg2="alpha"}
```

And it won't matter what order you put arg1/arg2 in.

You cannot, however, accept extra arguments without predefining them first, e.g if you tried to give the function four arguments inside the curly braces it would spit out an error.

Essentially what this is doing is inputting a table to a function with one parameter, then deriving information from that table rather than multiple parameters.

Comment: Great example, thank you. That style is working for me now.